# Looking for a LEGO promotional, Christmas-themed video game from the 90s-00s about spaceships

Tags: video-games, lego-games

This is one of my childhood white whales and I cannot find the answer anywhere.

When I grew up in France, I remember a very short computer game which was actually an ad for LEGO spaceships. Given the fact that I was born in 1996, and it was on a relatively early computer, I think it is from around 1999 to 2003, approximately. I could be wrong though. Here are the things I remember:

- The story starts, it's set in the snow. There is a small wooden house, a snowman, and probably Christmas-themed decoratons. It is a point and click game, I think, and a snowman gives you instructions.
- You find something (what?) and the snowman says "You should not trust the appearances!" (*"il ne faut pas se fier aux apparances !"*, sentence is stuck in my head since).
- The plot evolves, I think a spider is involved? The game is very short, in my memory.
- It ends with a spaceship race. You have to pick between three LEGO spaceships: a yellow one, a blue one and a red one. I think it is a minigame, you see the spaceship from behind and you have to dodge obstacles.
- When you win, the game ends. A screen, white and snow-themed, prompts you to get the Lego spaceships IRL. The three of them are displayed simultaneously on the screen.

This is all I remember and it is KILLING me. It's been bothering me for literal years, I looked everywhere in my parents' basement to find the CD, but couldn't.

Comment: Weird, there's nothing like that in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lego_video_games . See also https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info , BTW.

Comment: Thanks for those links. Indeed, nothing in the Wikipedia list.

Comment: Do you remember the shape of the spaceships? Have a look at the space sets from [1999](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?itemYear=1999&catString=34&catType=S), [2000](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?itemYear=2000&catString=34&catType=S), [2001](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?itemYear=2001&catString=34&catType=S), [2002](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?itemYear=2002&catString=34&catType=S) and [2003](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?itemYear=2003&catString=34&catType=S) and see if something jolts your memory.

Comment: Do you remember if this was a desktop game or if it was shockwave/flash based?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember... Back then, my dad also had a Commodore Amiga, but I think it was on his Windows computer. @IvanSanchez Unfortunately I don't have a specific memory, it is very blurry. Maybe the blue one looked like that: https://ideascdn.lego.com/media/generate/entity/lego_ci/project/b48f0a29-e7a7-4fcf-b612-a73e6a106e83/1/resize:1600:900/native, or something along these lines (very "traditional" spaceship shape).

Comment: @C.Crt That'd be around the [galaxy explorer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=928-1) era: 1979. It's unlikely that a videogame from the late 90s would be advertising lego sets from the early 80s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go on a hunch and say this is either [Lego Racers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Racers_(video_game)) from 1999, or [Lego Racers 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Racers_2) from 2001.

Both of these fit some of your criteria:

- The timeline (1999-2003)
- There's an ice level
- Last level is on an spaceship-themed alien planet
- They're rather short: a playthrough can be completed in about an hour.

But they don't fit the "point-and-click" criteria, which leads me to think your brain is confusing memories of (one of) these games with memories of some other point-and-click game. *It's hard to tell with the information you've provided*.

Judging by [gameplay videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2m1PnRptyM) of Lego Racers 2, the player drives a blue(-ish) car, the main opponent drives a red one, and cars flash yellow when using a power-up. This might have led you to think there's blue, red and yellow ships. The winner podium is red-yellow-blue as well.

In the second game, there's also an ice monster in the ice stage.